# how to pass special characters into ng-init in angularjs from python

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs

I am using ng-init to initialize some values on my page but I am having some issues when the values contain special characters.

Right now I use this syntax to pass the values from python to angular:

```
<span ng-init="company_name='{{ account.company_name|escape }}';"></span>
```

most of the time it works, but now I have an account name "idle-elephant's" which causes some issues.

I get the following error:

```
Error: [$parse:lexerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/undefined/$parse/lexerr?p0=Unterminated%20quote&p1=s%2029-31%20%5B'%3B%5D&p2=company_name%3D'idle-elephant's'%3B
```

How do I handle the string, so it passes the string correctly?

thanks
Thomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You escape it by adding a backslash before the single quote, so `idle-elephant's` should be outputted as `idle-elephant\'s`.

Comment: The thing is that I am getting the values from a DB, so I need a generalized way of handling strings with "illegal" characters. I was hoping there was a function to do this ?

Comment: The only things you need to worry about are to escape single quotes with a backslash, and make sure that the string doesn't contain a regular qoute, as that will "break" your `ng-init` attribute.