# How to escape single quotes in ng-init

Tags: angularjs, velocity, quote

Let's say we are passing data from apache velocity to angularjs and the data is some string that contain quotes,

the error on screen:

```
Error: [$parse:lexerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.22/$parse/lexerr?  
p0=Unterminated%20quote&p1=s%20327-
```

my code :

```
<span  ng-init='draftDemands=$draftDemands;'>
```

how to solve this problem

Comment: <span  ng-init='draftDemands=$draftDemands;'>

Comment: First, you don't need `;` at the end. Also, did you try with double quote ?

Comment: yes, it dnt work with double quote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i use $esc.xml($draftDemands), it work my last example,

Answer (score 0):

Are you escaping characters in Velocit's generated code? https://velocity.apache.org/tools/2.0/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/EscapeTool.html

Check also how angular does escaping via: [Strict Contextual Escaping](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce). So there is no need to render characters as HTML explicitly.

[This discussion could put some more light on the case](http://www.ngroutes.com/questions/AUuADEhNa5vEqxqlK4o3/single-double-quotes-in-ng-init.html).

This should also work: [how to pass special characters into ng-init in angularjs from python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22506091/how-to-pass-special-characters-into-ng-init-in-angularjs-from-python)

Comment: Have you tried: html($draftDemands)? Escapes the characters in a String using HTML entities.

Comment: i use this way #macro (escape $draftDemands)$esc.html($esc.javascript($draftDemands))#end

Comment: Are you able to debug/print out what's the velocity's output before putting it to angular code? That way you can isolate the problem to just one technology and then check further...

Comment: [{"id":1,"description":"xcvcxv","sample":"\n\tTove\n\tJani\n\tReminder\n\tDon't forget me this weekend!\n","variable":"xcv","constant":"xcvcx","constraint":"xcvcxv","status":"DRAFT","type":"XML","enterprise":{"id":2,"name":"XXX","version":0},"version":0,"encoding":"UTF-8","schema":"xcvxc"}]

Comment: the problem is in "don't" string

Comment: [{\"id\":1,\"description\":\"xcvcxv\",\"sample\":\"\\n\\tTove<\/to>\\n\\tJani<\/from>\\n\\tReminder<\/heading>\\n\\tDon\'t forget me this weekend!<\/body>\\n<\/note>\",\"variable\":\"xcv\",\"constant\":\"xcvcx\",\"constraint\":\"xcvcxv\",\"status\":\"DRAFT\",\"type\":\"XML\",\"enterprise\":{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"BNP\",\"version\":0},\"version\":0,\"encoding\":\"UTF-8\",\"schema\":\"xcvxc\"}])